# how do I add a SQL Server 2008 service instance?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I upgraded from SQl server 05 to 08 and had a few issues. After uninstalling 05 and a few restarts later 08 installed okay, but now I don't have any SQL Server services running.

I can't connect to (local)\SQLExpress or .\SQLEXPRESS via SQL Server management studio and the SQL Server services dialog shows no services. There's no add button anywhere there, so how do I add a new service?

Do I have do this programmatically or something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've had similar issues and the solution we used was to reinstall SQL server 2008 and at the point where it asks you for default instance or named instance, used a named instance and continue on.

This does not affect any currently installed instances but creates a new instance of the name supplied and then from there on should be usable.

Answer (score 4):

If it's an instance you want to create you might wanna have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265081/how-to-create-default-instance-after-creating-a-named-instance) - it might work the same way