# Run SQL server 2008 instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have SQL server 2008 and 2005 installed on one machine. I came to know that the SQL 2005 version is running as default. My question is how can i change the SQL to run 2008 version?

your help will be appreciated greatly

Thanks

Comment: Is your question about migrating the sql 2005 to sql 2008 or to set the sql 2008 instance as the default instance ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to change the named instance to default ....
You have to reinstall...

I found one site which showed a combination of:
sp_dropserver nameofinstance
sp_addserver machinename,'local'

and some registry hacks.

[Resource Link.](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/microsoft.public.sqlserver.server/VExOr0Pd-vM)

Answer (score 1):

It's actually possible.

1. drop current instname (sp_dropserver)
2. add new instance name (sp_addserver 'new name','local')
3. stop sqlserver
4. modify hklm\software\microsoft\microsoft sql server\
5. modify hklm\system\mssql$
6. use "sc create" to add new mssql$
7. start up with new inst_name

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible to make a named instance the defautl instance. Reasons are given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35026/sql-server-convert-a-named-instance-to-default-instance).

But if you need to have a sql 2008 as default instance a method is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265081/how-to-create-default-instance-after-creating-a-named-instance). You have to installe a new instance and set it as the default one.